# in a good health or on a good health

Tags: prepositions

Here is one question:
My grandpa is old, but he is ___good health.
A. at  B. in  C. of  D. on
The correct answer is "in" but I guess in, of or on may be ok too?

Comment: Interesting question. We say that someone is **in** good health, but **of** sound mind. I don't know why. Maybe that should be your question?

Comment: I don't think there is only one correct answer to the question, although the questioner set the only one answer is "in". Can "on" be good here too?

Comment: **on** is **never** right here. It's **in good health** with no **a**. None of the others is correct.

Answer (score 3):

As with many English idioms, there is one and only one right preposition that goes with the phrase, which you have no choice but to memorize.

> My grandfather is **in** good health.

*On* or *of* or *at* or *with* or any of the others don't work, because it's just not the way it is. Other examples:

> I went for a checkup and the doctor said that while I am in good health now, I really should exercise more often.
>
> She insisted, through her persistent coughing, that she was still in good health.

Interestingly enough, as Mick points out in his comment, you can be **of** sound mind and body (= "**in** good mental and physical health").  But not *of* good health.

Comment: What about: *He's of good health, a sound mind, a good background, suitable parents*? I'm just asking; perhaps *of good health* is not impossible, say if describing a person's background.

Comment: @AlanCarmack if I just say the phrases naturally, it would be *in* good health, *of* sound mind, *with* a good background, and *having* suitable parents.  We can, for example, "speak of *good health*" but the meaning is different from the idiom "in good health".